# I cant place or set background or border of my user control

Tags: xaml

I've created a simple user control for my xaml project, but as you can see from my image i cant seem to be able to do certain things.

[image]

*Ignore the red line, its the size of the control for illustrate its size.*

It's placement should be middle of the screen:

```
<Client:TileMenu HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="TileOverlayMenu" Background="Azure" BorderBrush="Aquamarine" BorderThickness="3" />
```

And as you see its background color should be "Azure" with a blueish border of 3.

Why is this?

In the background I have a Canvas:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,0,12,0">

            <Canvas Name="GameCanvas">

                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform x:Name="CanvasRenderTransform" />
                </Canvas.RenderTransform>

                <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
                    <toolkit:GestureListener DragStarted="GestureListener_DragStarted" DragDelta="GestureListener_DragDelta" Tap="GestureListener_Tap" PinchStarted="GestureListener_PinchStarted" PinchDelta="GestureListener_PinchDelta"/>
                </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>

            </Canvas>

            <Client:TileMenu HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Name="TileOverlayMenu" Background="Azure" BorderBrush="Aquamarine" BorderThickness="3" />

        </Grid>
```

As for my third problem, having the events in the canvas causes the Move slider to be interrupted, making me only able to push it a little each time :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case `TileMenu` is a UserControl you would have to set these properties on the top level container in the UserControl's XAML as this defines the entire visual structure of the control.

You could bind to the appropriate values in the UserControl, however:

```
<UserControl x:Class="YourNamespace.TileMenu" ...
             x:Name="tileMenu">
    <Border BorderBrush="{Binding BorderBrush, ElementName=tileMenu}"
            BorderThickness="{Binding BorderThickness, ElementName=tileMenu}">
        <Grid>
            ...
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```